# Can't manage DFS namespace after retiring namespace server

Tags: windows-server, microsoft-distributed-file-system

In DFS Management, when we try to manage one of the namespaces, the error is:

> \\mydomain.com\mynamespace: The namespace cannot be queried. The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

When I use `dfsdiag /testdfsintegrity /dfsroot:\\mydomain.com\mynamespace`, the output is:

```
Error: The RPC server is unavailable.
Error: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
Warning: Unable to access the DFS metadata for the following namespace: \\myserver\mynamespace
Finished TestDfsIntegrity.
```

We retired *myserver* within the last few months. I speculate that it was the only namespace server for this namespace. I can still browse this namespace in file explorer; I just can't manage it in DFS Management.

Is there a way to set up another server to be the namespace server for this namespace?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete the namespace and recreate it.

Before deleting it, I needed to record what folders were in the namespace. Fortunately, I could still browse the namespace in file explorer. I made notes about what everything was pointing to.

I could not use the DFS Management tool to manage the namespace at all. To delete it, I did the following:

1. Run **adsiedit.msc**.
2. Connect to the default naming context.
3. Navigate to **DC=*mydomain*, DC=com** > **CN=System** > **CN=Dfs-Configuration**.
4. There is listed all of the namespaces. Delete the problem one.
5. Running the commands "repadmin /syncall" and "dfsrdiag pollad"
   supposedly cause everything to sync up.
6. Then I could use DFS Management to recreate the namespace.